# ordering fields after applying $setUnion mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

**I have a collection:**

```
        {
"_id" : ObjectId("5338ec2a5b5b71242a1c911c"),
"people" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Vasya"
    }, 
    {
        "age" : "30"
    }, 
    {
        "weight" : "80"
    }
],
"animals" : [ 
    {
        "dog" : "Sharick"
    }, 
    {
        "cat" : "Barsik"
    }, 
    {
        "bird" : "parrot"
    }
]},{
"_id" : ObjectId("5338ec7f5b5b71242a1c911d"),
"people" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "Max"
    }, 
    {
        "age" : "32"
    }, 
    {
        "weight" : "78"
    }
],
"animals" : [ 
    {
        "dog" : "Borbos"
    }, 
    {
        "cat" : "Murka"
    }, 
    {
        "bird" : "Eagle"
    }
]}
```

**then I combine two arrays "people" and "animals"**

```
db.tmp.aggregate({$project:{"union":{$setUnion:["$people","$animals"]}}})
```

**in the issue:**

How to make the fields of each record array "result" to be displayed in a single order, and not randomly?
that is:

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could find the quote ( If I can I will add it ), but it basically comes from the CTO of MongoDB and is essentially (sic) "Set's are **not** considered to be ordered". And very much so from a Math point of view that **is** true.

So you have stumbled upon one of the new features in the current (as of writing) 2.6 release candidate series. But like with it's $addToSet counterpart, the resulting **set** from $setUnion will **not** be sorted in any way.

To do this you need to $unwind and $sort and then $group again using $push,  just as you always have with $addToSet. And of course you would need some common key in order to $sort on this, which your data does not.

Update: Here is the [**quote**](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8512), and [**here is another**](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6258).

Comment: Thanks Neil, maybe later will be more than a simple way.

Comment: @timkit Read the JIRA issues that are both marked **will not fix**. The comments on them are from the CTO. This will never happen.